# Working thru sample code

Tags: c#

I am trying to work thru some sample code.
The code I am having a problem with is:

```
private ListControl GetSelectedList()
{
  return (ListControl)FindControl(ddlControls.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

`ddlControls` is a DropDownListBoxControl collection
What does the `ddlControls.SelectedItem.Value` return (its a numeric value, but I don't know what it represents)?

2nd question: What is `return (ListControl)FindControl(ddlControls.SelectedItem.Value);` ?

Thanks

Comment: -1 I'd suggest to think a bit and learn how to properly define your question. The subject is completely unclear. Not to mention you don't use English correctly. Second, use formatting for code. Third, use tags. Simply, don't be lazy and read the SO FAQ and follow the 3 bullets of the first question.

Comment: mloskot: Be a little bit gentler than that, SO embraces all questions, not to scare off people, SO wants to be the best 'google' for questions and answers...see here..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers
The tone of your comment is inherently harsh so go easy on them...

Comment: @tommieb75 OK, perhaps it is a little harsh, but I'm not commenting it is lmgtfy issue but the style in which this question has been asked. Working thru? What's that? It's a clear indicator I'm too lazy to type the word through, inappropriate attitude I believe. What's next? Posting questions in SMS language?

Comment: @mloskot: Yeah.... I know what you mean - I absolutely hate it when people use text speak when emailing or posting a question like that -p.i.t.a - I back you on it 100%... absolutely it's terrible..I am a strict person when it comes to spelling and would tell anyone off if they ever used text speak....I did that a few days ago, commented on that on another question and was told to go easy on the poor poster... :P but you are quite right...sorry if I jumped down your throat....after you expressed your view, you're 100% spot on!

Comment: @tommieb75 No problem. I admit I could be more polite to LearningCSharp user as well.

Comment: @mloskot y dnt u like sms talk? bit of timsvr, dnt u thnk? Will keep my dkshnry hndy nxt time.

Comment: @LearningCSharp - when people are defending you, it would be as well good to avoid such kind of silly answer. Unless you just want to prove his point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectedItem.Value`, as the name suggests, is the value of the currently selected item in the drop-down list. For example, if this were a list of months and someone had selected "September", this property has the value "September".

> what is return (ListControl)FindControl(ddlControls.SelectedItem.Value);

**[`FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa334218%28VS.71%29.aspx)** is a method that looks up controls by their id. Using our example from before, it would try to find a control with the name "September". The `(ListControl)` at the beginning is a **[cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105%28VS.80%29.aspx)**; the `GetSelectedList()` method is implicitly assuming that every possible answer you could get from `ddlControls` is the name of another `ListControl`. (This might not be a good idea depending on the circumstances.)

The result -- that is, the control whose id is the same as the currently selected value in `ddlControls` -- is then returned, and that's the result of `GetSelectedList()`.

Comment: John, thanks for your reply. I guess this ia a bit complex, but I think I understand the gist of what you are saying. Complex because this is probably a way to locate a control at runtime (which I have not done in the past). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[DropDownList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) in MSDN has the answer to the first question.  In particular, it links to [ListControl.SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem.aspx), which is defined as:

> If the list control allows only a single selection, use this property to get the individual properties of the selected item. If the list control allows multiple selections, use this property to get the properties of the lowest indexed item selected from the list control.

Similarly, [Control.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) gives the answer to your second question.  It's defined as:

> Searches the current naming container for a server control with the specified id parameter.